# <td> taking up space when using display: none

Tags: html, css, razor

I'm brand new at media queries, pretty new to .net in general, and MAYbe I've been staring at this code for too long, so please be kind.

I'm trying to make the 1st td totally disappear at max-width 775px and replace it with the second td. It appears that the first td is just becoming "invisible" but is still taking up space. 
I added the borders only as visual aids.
ANY help would be appreciated!

```css
@media screen and (min-width:776px) {
  .hidey {
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
  .hidey2 {
    display: none;
    border: 1px dashed red;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:775px) {
  .hidey {
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    display: none;
  }
  .hidey2 {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Blah:</th>
    <td class="hidey" style="width: 20em; "><span>td one</span>
    </td>
    <td class="hidey2" style="width: 20em;"><span>td two</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[View 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08HKp.jpg)

[View 2, with unwanted space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/820Mc.jpg)

Comment: Is there any reason that you have `@@media` instead of just `@media`? Additionally, you have a closing `</span>` element without any opening `<span>` tags, which could explain your issue.

Comment: Works as expected (with one at-sign in `@media`): https://jsfiddle.net/brfssy24/ You'll have to show a demo that replicates the behavior. It's possible that you're not hiding all the cells in the column.

Comment: @Jujucat In CSS, `@` does not escape and `@@` is invalid.

Comment: If you are using this within ASP.NET Razor views (or something similar), then it could be an escape. However even without that, I can't seem to reproduce your issue with the extra spacing.

Comment: Posting a question with syntax errors that, when fixed, does not reproduce the problem, is a good way to attract downvotes.

Comment: Oh, duh. Thanks for the explanation @RionWilliams. I am using razor. Sorry for that.

Answer (score -1):

**Invalid Markup and Syntax**

This is likely an issue with your markup due to the following :

- You are prefacing your media queries with `@@media` instead of just `@media` which would be invalid in most scenarios (outside of escaping in something like an ASP.NET Razor View).
- You have closing `</span>` elements within your `<td>` elements without any opening `<span>` elements, which would be invalid as well.

Additionally, you can probably consolidate your queries as well :

```
@media screen and (min-width:776px) {
  .hidey { border: 1px solid blue; }
  .hidey2 { display: none; border: 1px dashed red; }
}
@media screen and (max-width:775px) {
  .hidey { border: 1px dashed blue;  display: none; }
  .hidey2 { border: 1px solid red; }
}
```

**Example**

Your example code appears to work just as expected, even within [an MVC Razor View as seen in this interactive example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RgYFc2) and demonstrate below :

[image]

```css
@media screen and (min-width:776px) {
  .hidey { border: 1px solid blue; }
  .hidey2 { display: none; border: 1px dashed red; }
}
@media screen and (max-width:775px) {
  .hidey { border: 1px dashed blue;  display: none; }
  .hidey2 { border: 1px solid red; }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Blah:</th>
    <td class="hidey" style="width: 20em; "><span>td one</span></td>
    <td class="hidey2" style="width: 20em;"><span>td two</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah, I'd corrected the span issue earlier. That was a copy/paste issue. My bad. The double @'s are needed, as I'm in a razor view. Unfortunately, the code is still not working for me. I'm sure you'd need to see more of my code in order to form a proper answer. I had just hoped that I had made a mistake in the code I posted. Unfortunately, I didn't. :(

Comment: Multiple rows shouldn't make a difference as your media queries will be applied on the class of the `<td>` elements. Is there any way you could screenshot the issue you are referring to as I don't really see much wrong after the proposed changes.

Comment: I have added screenshots. Hope that's what you're after.

Comment: It's still a bit hard to tell without the exact markup to reproduce it. At first glance, it looks like it might be an issue relating to missing tags, but it's nearly impossible to tell. Sorry.

Comment: Well, I appreciate your attention. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
    @media only screen {
        .hidey1 {
            display: none;
        }
        .hidey2 {
            display: table;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 775px) {
        .hidey1 {
            display: table;
        }
        .hidey2 {
            display: none;
        }
    }
</style>  

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="hidey1">td one</td>
        <td class="hidey2">td two</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While pasted piece of code may or may not be a working solution to the problem, making an answer may also require to providing an explanation and context. Please read the help file on [answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).